# Custom Python Model constructor

Tags: python, class, object

I have built a custom model that allows me to save to Airtable from a MySQL query. The goal is to pass the base name and key from a loop of base keys and table names, and have the model use the save function which was working before the last adjustment. I cannot figure out what the change was, I have commented out everything but:

```
daily_kpi=Daily_KPI(base_key=base['base_key'], table_name=base['table_name'])
```

And I still get an error.

```
class Daily_KPI(at.AT):
    base_key=None
    table_name='Daily'

    #Fields

    @property
    def ID(self):
        dt=datetime.strptime(self.date, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%m/%d/%y')
        return str(dt)+" "+self.sku+" "+self.account

    date=at.ATField(field_name="date", at_field_name="Date")
    asin=at.ATField(field_name="asin", at_field_name="ASIN")
    account=at.ATField(field_name="account", at_field_name="Account")
    # country=at.ATField(field_name="country", at_field_name="Country")
    sessions=at.ATField(field_name="sessions", at_field_name="Sessions")
    session_pct=at.ATField(field_name="session_pct", at_field_name="Session Pct")
    page_views=at.ATField(field_name="page_views", at_field_name="Page Views")
    page_view=at.ATField(field_name="page_view", at_field_name="Page View")
    buy_box=at.ATField(field_name="buy_box", at_field_name="Buy Box")
    units_ordered=at.ATField(field_name="units_ordered", at_field_name="Units Ordered")
    units_ord_b2b=at.ATField(field_name="units_ord_b2b", at_field_name="Units Ord B2B")
    unit_session=at.ATField(field_name="unit_session", at_field_name="Unit Session")
    ord_prod=at.ATField(field_name="ord_prod", at_field_name="Ord Prod")
    ord_prod_b2b=at.ATField(field_name="ord_prod_b2b", at_field_name="Ord Prod B2B")
    tot_ord_items=at.ATField(field_name="tot_ord_items", at_field_name="Tot Ord Items")
    tot_ord_b2b=at.ATField(field_name="tot_ord_b2b", at_field_name="Tot Ord B2B")
    bsr=at.ATField(field_name="bsr", at_field_name="B.S.R")
    actual_sales=at.ATField(field_name="actual_sales", at_field_name="Actual Sales")
    selling_price=at.ATField(field_name="selling_price", at_field_name="Selling Price")
    notes=at.ATField(field_name="notes", at_field_name="Notes")
    unit_sess_b2b=at.ATField(field_name="unit_sess_b2b", at_field_name="Unit Sess B2B")
    sku=at.ATField(field_name="sku", at_field_name="SKU")

    def __init__(self, base_key, table_name):
        super(Daily_KPI, self).__init__(base_key=base_key, table_name=table_name)
```

When I try to use the model,

```
    def save_data(self):
    try:
        print ('hello')
        #wp_table=Airtable(BASE_KEY, 'Weekly Profitability Development copy', API_KEY)
        results = self.results
        print(len(results))
        for base in settings.DAILY_AIRTABLE:
            for row in self.results:
                try:
                    daily_kpi=Daily_KPI(base_key=base['base_key'], table_name=base['table_name'])
                    daily_kpi.date=str(date.today())
                    # daily_kpi.sku = row['ItemSKU']
                    # daily_kpi.asin = row['ASIN']
                    # daily_kpi.account = row['Account']
                    # daily_kpi.sessions = row['Sessions']
                    # daily_kpi.session_pct = row['Session_Pct']
                    # daily_kpi.page_view = row['Page_Views']
                    # daily_kpi.page_view_pct = row['Page_Views_Pct']
                    # daily_kpi.buy_box = row['Buy_Box_Pct']
                    # daily_kpi.units_ordered = row['Units_Ordered']
                    # daily_kpi.units_ordered_b2b = row['Units_Ordered_B2B']
                    # daily_kpi.unit_session_pct=row['Unit_Session_Pct']
                    # daily_kpi.unit_session_pct_b2b= row['Unit_Session_Pct_B2B']
                    # daily_kpi.ord_prod=row['Ordered_Product_Sales']
                    # daily_kpi.ord_prod_b2b=row['Ordere_Product_Sales_B2B']
                    # daily_kpi.tot_ord_items=row['Total_Order_Items']
                    # daily_kpi.tot_ord_b2b=row['Total_Order_Items_B2B']
                    # daily_kpi.bsr=row['BSR']
                    # daily_kpi.actual_sales
                    # daily_kpi.selling_price
                    # daily_kpi.notes
                    # daily_kpi.unit_sess_b2b
                    # daily_kpi.sku
                    daily_kpi.save()
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
```

I get error: `super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`

I am not quite sure how to adjust the constructor so that it accepts the parameters and creates an object. I tried

```
    def __init__(self, base_key, table_name):
    super(Daily_KPI, self).__init__(self, base_key=base_key, table_name=table_name)
```

Comment: I would like to try to help, is there a python api for `Airtable`? Do we need an Airtable account to reproduce your results? I created an account but can't find a `python` api in Airtable.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple airtable Pytbon client. It would be fairly easy to do what you described with it:
https://github.com/gtalarico/airtable-python-wrapper